# The integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \int_{|x - y| \geq 1} \dfrac{|u(x)|^p}{|x - y|^{N+sp}}dxdy$ is finite?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $s \in (0,1)$ and $p \in [1,\infty)$. If $u \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$, it is possible to conclude that the integral
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \int_{|x - y| \geq 1} \dfrac{|u(x)|^p}{|x - y|^{N+sp}}dxdy$$
is finite?

**Remark**: I looked for the strategy of using a change of variables in the form $z = x - y$, but the numerator of the quotient would depend on $z + y$, which would make it impossible to have the following expression
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |u(x)|^p \left(\int_{|z| \geq 1} \dfrac{1}{|z|^{N+sp}}dz\right)dx < \infty.$$

Comment: What is $|x-y|$? The Euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R}^N$?

Comment: Yes, it is Euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: Change $y$ instead of $x$ ...

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand. Could you explain it to me in more detail?

Comment: What LL 3.14 is saying is that you should still take $z = x - y$ but instead of considering the change of variables $(x,y) \to (z,y)$ like you did, you should rather go with $(x,y) \to (x,z)$. Btw, to make sure LL 3.14 got your message asking for clarification, you need to ping them with @ + username (you can let the site auto-complete after typing the first letter or first few letters). For example if I wanted to talk to you under someone else's post, I would type @Santos. It's not needed when you're talking to the poster of the question or answer you're commenting under, but otherwise it is.